# dart flutter: How to rotate around circle?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to get the square to respond to the Gesture Detector for
rotating the square around a circle. Turning it clockwise should give
a positive increase from 0 to 360 and anticlockwise should decrease from
360 to 0. But here it increases beyond 360 and also goes below 0 into
minus values. And the response to the drag is unpredictable.

The square should rotate only if IT detects the gesture and not the circle
behind it.

I don't know even if this is the way to go about it. Any help will be very
much appreciated. I've been at this for some days now.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
  [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
 runApp(new MyRotateApp());
}

class MyRotateApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyRotateAppState createState() {
    return new MyRotateAppState();
  }
 }

class MyRotateAppState extends State<MyRotateApp> {
  double angleDelta;
  String strDialAngle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    angleDelta = -90.0; //start from top position
    strDialAngle = 'Angle Text';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('ROTATE Square')),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Stack(alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          height: 350.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueGrey, shape: BoxShape.circle),
        ),
        /// position the square
        new MyRadialPosition(
            radius: 130.0,
            angle: angleDelta * PI / 180.0,
            /// Gesture Detector
            child: new GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
              child: new Container(
                width: 45.0,
                height: 45.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            )),
        /// update text based on angle value of rotation of square
        new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
          child: new Text('$strDialAngle',
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0,color: Colors.white),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _onVerticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    angleDelta = angleDelta + (details.delta.dy).roundToDouble();
    strDialAngle = 'VERTICAL Drag : ${angleDelta + 90.0}';
    setState((){});
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    angleDelta = angleDelta + (details.delta.dx).roundToDouble();
    strDialAngle = 'Horizontal Drag : ${angleDelta + 90.0}';
    setState((){});
  }
}

class MyRadialPosition extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double angle;
  final Widget child;
  MyRadialPosition({this.radius, this.angle, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final x = radius * cos(angle);
    final y = radius * sin(angle);
    return new Transform(
      transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(x, y, 0.0),
      child: child,);
  }
}

// for adding to the above Stack RadialDragGestureDetector
new MyRadialPosition(radius: 170.0,
         angle: angleDelta * PI / 180.0,
         child: new RadialDragGestureDetector(
           onRadialDragUpdate: _onRadialDragUpdate,
           child: new Container(
           width: 45.0,
           height: 45.0,
           color: Colors.amber,
       ),
         ),
       ),

_onRadialDragUpdate(PolarCoord updateCoord) {
setState((){
  angleDelta = (updateCoord.angle).roundToDouble();
  print('updateCoord.angle : ${(updateCoord.angle).roundToDouble()}');
});
}
```

Comment: I think one of the problems you're facing is that `onVerticalDragUpdate` and `onHorizontalDragUpdate` do not happen simultaneously. If you move your finger on a curve, only the horizontal or the vertical component of your move will be interpreted, hence the apparent unpredictability.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `Draggable` Widget class in the docs in the docs to track the user's moves. Its `feedbackOffset` property might be what you're looking for.
Maybe the `PointerMoveEvent` could be useful as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with simple calculation on `panUpdate` and `panEnd`:

```
 _panUpdateHandler(DragUpdateDetails d) {
/// Pan location on the wheel
bool onTop = d.localPosition.dy <= radius;
bool onLeftSide = d.localPosition.dx <= radius;
bool onRightSide = !onLeftSide;
bool onBottom = !onTop;

/// Pan movements
bool panUp = d.delta.dy <= 0.0;
bool panLeft = d.delta.dx <= 0.0;
bool panRight = !panLeft;
bool panDown = !panUp;

/// Absolute change on axis
double yChange = d.delta.dy.abs();
double xChange = d.delta.dx.abs();

/// Directional change on wheel
double verticalRotation = (onRightSide && panDown) || (onLeftSide && panUp)
    ? yChange
    : yChange * -1;

double horizontalRotation =
    (onTop && panRight) || (onBottom && panLeft) ? xChange : xChange * -1;

// Total computed change
double rotationalChange = verticalRotation + horizontalRotation;

double _value = degree + (rotationalChange / 5);

setState(() {
  degree = _value > 0 ? _value : 0;
  ctrl.value = degree;
});
}
```

On pan end:

```
_panEndHandler(DragEndDetails d) {
ctrl
    .animateTo(roundToBase(degree.roundToDouble(), 10),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 551), curve: Curves.easeOutBack)
    .whenComplete(() {
  setState(() {
    degree = roundToBase(degree.roundToDouble(), 10);
  });
});
}
```

And then attach them to a gesture detector:

```
GestureDetector draggableWheel = GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: _panUpdateHandler,
  onPanEnd: _panEndHandler,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: ctrl,
        builder: (ctx, w) {
          return Transform.rotate(
            angle: degreeToRadians(ctrl.value),
            child: wheelContainer,
          );
        },
      ),
      Container(
        width: wheelSize,
        height: wheelSize / 2,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: this.longNeedleHeight + 10),
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://d20nqim3b55fln.cloudfront.net/images/ic_needle_light.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: wheelSize,
        height: wheelSize,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: WheelDecoration(context),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Here is the full example for your reference:
codepen link: https://codepen.io/godwinvc/pen/oNxrOeX

```css
iframe {
  display:block;
    vertical-align:top;
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
  
}
```

```html
<iframe style="overflow-y: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; display:block; vertical-align:top;" src="https://codepen.io/godwinvc/full/oNxrOeX"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fluttery package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluttery#-example-tab-). It has [radial drag gesture detector](https://github.com/matthew-carroll/fluttery/blob/master/example/lib/example_radial_drag.dart).

```
      child: new RadialDragGestureDetector(
        onRadialDragStart: _onRadialDragStart,
        onRadialDragUpdate: _onRadialDragUpdate,
        onRadialDragEnd: _onRadialDragEnd,
        child: new ...
```

and listeners get `PolarCoord` on start and update so you can see radians.

You didnt mention if you do one or two finger gesture, so let me know if this helps

Comment: I'm using one finger gesture. I had tried 'RadialDragGestureDetector' but  could not get it to work. Here is the code added to the above stack :

Comment: Check this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE7Vtzq52xg He is the creator of the package, and has code on github

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it. I was looking for implementing the gesture to be received only by the small green square and not the Circle behind it. Is there any way else one might go about it.

Comment: you would change the listener to the square, instead of the circle around it, then the rest of the mechanics would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onPanUpdate.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class MyRotateApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyRotateAppState createState() {
    return new MyRotateAppState();
  }
}

class MyRotateAppState extends State<MyRotateApp> {
  double angleDelta;
  String strDialAngle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    angleDelta = -90.0; //start from top position
    strDialAngle = 'Angle Text';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('ROTATE Square')),
          body: new Center(
            child: new Stack(alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  height: 260.0,
                  width: 260.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                ),
                /// position the square
                new MyRadialPosition(
                    radius: 130.0,
                    angle: angleDelta * 3.142 / 180.0,
                    /// Gesture Detector
                    child: new GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
//                      onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
//                      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
                      child: new Container(
                        width: 45.0,
                        height: 45.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    )),
                /// update text based on angle value of rotation of square
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
                  child: new Text('$strDialAngle',
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0,color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _onVerticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    angleDelta = angleDelta + (details.delta.dy).roundToDouble();
    strDialAngle = 'VERTICAL Drag : ${angleDelta + 90.0}';
    setState((){});
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    angleDelta = angleDelta + (details.delta.dx).roundToDouble();
    strDialAngle = 'Horizontal Drag : ${angleDelta + 90.0}';
    setState((){});
  }

  //use onPanUpdate here
  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    Offset center = Offset(130.0, 130.0);
    var a = (details.delta.dx) - center.dx;
    var b = center.dy - (details.delta.dy);

    angleDelta = angleDelta + atan2(b, a);
    setState(() {
    });
  }
}

class MyRadialPosition extends StatelessWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double angle;
  final Widget child;
  MyRadialPosition({this.radius, this.angle, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final x = radius * cos(angle);
    final y = radius * sin(angle);
    return new Transform(
      transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(x, y, 0.0),
      child: child,);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work, as the square rotates around on the circle. But I am looking to control the square and be able to reverse it, should I change the direction of thumb movement, clockwise / anti-clockwise. Thanks.